# Does requiring from the standard library make a program slower?

Tags: ruby, import, require, standard-library

I’m thinking of ruby specifically when I ask this question, but if the answer is language-agnostic, I’d like to know as well.

I often `require` from the ruby standard library, namely `fileutils`, `open3`, and `pathname`.

But if I only need to use their capabilities in one or two lines, I avoid them and go for (sometimes less readable) alternatives that don’t need a `require`.

However, using them doesn’t appear to hurt performance of my scripts, and even with quick benchmarks (using `time`), things seem to run at the same speed they would if I used different methods. But it seems weird to me it would make no difference, because why then have them be `require`d for use (and not just included outright)? So, specific questions:

1. Does importing from the standard library make scripts slower?
2. If so, is it always negligible, or does it depend on the package?
3. What about third-party packages? Are they slower to import than the ones in the standard library?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Ruby doesn't lazy-load libraries, so there would definitely be some overhead. With regard to a standard library, I presume Ruby ships them as dylibs (though that's a guess), so there would be very little overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing a library will take a non-zero amount of time, but the amount of time is directly proportional to what library. Some are very small, some much larger, but all of the ones that ship with Ruby are usually quick to load.

Unless you're running your script a thousand times a second the impact of a `require` is going to be minimal.

It's usually better to get all the `require` operations out of the way as early as possible to shake out any dependency problems, especially with gems. There's nothing worse than code that crashes because of a broken dependency, but only when you perform a particular action that doesn't happen often.

If you are starting this process thousands of times over, consider a tool like [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) or your own forking model to avoid the startup penalty. You can `fork` a pre-configured process any number of times, each of which will be ready nearly instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

When using `require` you are telling Ruby to load some file (your own file, standard library or external library).

So yes, it takes time to find and load it.

But the required file is loading [only once](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require) (usually at start because usually `require` at the top of file).

> Loads the given `name`, returning `true` if successful and `false` if the feature is already loaded.
>
> The absolute path of the loaded file is added to `$LOADED_FEATURES` (`$"`). A file will not be loaded again if its path already appears in `$"`

And the time spent depends on the file size and the size of the associated files.